# An application of Birkhoff ergodic theorem

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $(X,B,m)$ be the particular probability space where $X$ is the circle in the plane with center at the origin and radius 1, $B$ is the collection of borel sets, $m$ is the lebesgue measure. Let $T:X\rightarrow X$ denote rotation by $\frac{2\pi }{3}$ radians. We know that $T$ is measure preserving. Let $A$ be the set of points $(x,y)\in X$ with $x>0$ and $y>0$ and let f be the indicator function of $A$. What will be the explicit description of $f^*$ in the Birkhoff ergodic theorem ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am sorry, this is rather simple.

Answer (score 2):

Davide, I believe this is how it works:

we observe that  $\frac{1}{3k-1}\sum^{3k-1}_{i=0}f(T^i(x))=\frac{k}{3k-1}(f(x)+f(T(x)+f(T^2(x))$ , then from Birkhoff's Ergodic Throem taking the limit we have :

$f^*(x)=\frac{1}{3}(f(x)+f(T(x)+f(T^2(x))$, now we can use the definition of $f$ to write $f^*$ explicitly.

Comment: Birkhoff ergodic theorem does not seem to come into play here.

Comment: Did, the theorem is not supposed to come into play, the problem is about finding the explicit representation of the limit function in the theorem in this particular case.

Comment: Quote: `from Birkhoff's Ergodic Throem taking the limit`. Well, not from BET.

Comment: Isn't the system ergodic, so that $f^{*}$ is constant and equal to $\int_{X} f \, dm = \frac{1}{4}$ a.e.?